# update a get request to elastic search in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to hit a get request on my elastic search index using JSONelastisearchprocessor in NIFI.
Now, for each flow file i have some incoming attributes, based on that i need to generate different get request and store the response somewhere.

The list of processors i'm using is as below:

1. Getfile (to read JSON file)
2. Evaluate JSON path (To extract the attributes which i want to use with every get request, PROC_INST_ID_ in this case )
3. JSON queryelastic search (to hit the request with the below )
4. PUTfile to store the response

**Request body**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "los",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "los.${proc_ins_id}":"784525" }},
            { "match": { "los._source.cibilPermission.VALUE_":"1" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see the request being genrated and not getting any response instead i'm only getting the value of proc_ins_id as reponse in putfile. Can someone suggest some appropriate way to do this?

Attaching relevant screenshots as well for reference.

[image: NIfi_fow]
[image: evaluatejson]

Comment: Maybe is related to how flowfiles looks like and the configuration of putfile processor, could you add this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are providing the request body in the `Query` property of `JsonQueryElasticSearch`. In that case, you should set the `Destination` property to `flowfile-attribute` in `EvaluateJsonPath` because if it is set to `flowfile-content` and the `Query` property is configured with an actual query, JsonQueryElasticSearch won't even read the content of the flowfile.

And also connect `hits` and `original` to two different processors because if you connect them to the same processor you would get the `original` flowfile which was updated at `EvaluateJsonPath` at the directory configured in `PutFile`. In general, people would auto-terminate the `original` relationships unless there is a need to have it. You may also need to have the `aggregations` relationship configured as well because the aggregation results are sent to that relationship.

Comment: Accepted. Just one more question what exactly aggregations relationship means in nifi?

Comment: You can run aggregations query in Elasticsearch. The results of the aggregations query are returned through this relationship.